# Google Map crash on Android app

Tags: android, google-maps

Someday the code crash...
My AndroidManifiest is correct even mi API credentials, my internet conecction  works fine.
I am using Android Studio , the SDK are installed too.

Here is the Logcat

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int   java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.VanWhi$ParserTask.onPostExecute(VanWhi.java:139)
        at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.VanWhi$ParserTask.onPostExecute(VanWhi.java:113)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

And this is the Fragment

```
public class VanWhi extends FragmentActivity {


private static final LatLng VANCOUVER = new LatLng(  49.281612,   -123.115464);
private static final LatLng WHISLER = new LatLng(  50.116966, -122.956546);

GoogleMap googleMap;
final String TAG = "PathGoogleMapActivity";

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vanwhi);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);



    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    googleMap = fm.getMap();
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
    googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
    options.position(VANCOUVER);
    options.position(WHISLER);
    googleMap.addMarker(options);
    String url = getMapsApiDirectionsUrl();
    ReadTask downloadTask = new ReadTask();
    downloadTask.execute(url);

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(VANCOUVER,
            6));
    addMarkers();

}

private String getMapsApiDirectionsUrl() {
    String waypoints = "waypoints=optimize:true|"

            + "|" + "|" + VANCOUVER.latitude + ","
            + VANCOUVER.longitude + "|" + WHISLER.latitude + ","
            + WHISLER.longitude;

    String sensor = "sensor=false";
    String params = waypoints + "&" + sensor;
    String output = "json";
    String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"
            + output + "?" + params;
    return url;
}

private void addMarkers() {
    if (googleMap != null) {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(VANCOUVER)
                .title("VANCOUVER"));

        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(WHISLER)
                .title("WHISTLER"));

    }
}

private class ReadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        String data = "";
        try {
            HttpConnection http = new HttpConnection();
            data = http.readUrl(url[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        new ParserTask().execute(result);
    }
}

private class ParserTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

    @Override
    protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
            String... jsonData) {

        JSONObject jObject;
        List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
            PathJSONParser parser = new PathJSONParser();
            routes = parser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return routes;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes) {
        ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
        PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;

        // traversing through routes
        for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
            points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
            polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
            List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                points.add(position);
            }

            polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
            polyLineOptions.width(8);
            polyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
        }

        googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is from `info.androidhive.slidingmenu` and not from the Fragment you sent.
It's a nullpointer exception from a null List<>

you don't check if `routes != null` and `path != null` before your loops, maybe the json deserialisation failed, so those lists are nul

Comment: you don't check if `routes != null` and `path != null` before your loops, maybe the json deserialisation failed, so those lists are null